# How to scrape metrics-server to prometheus outside kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics-server

I have installed kubernetes metrics-server https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server It works fine, I can use "kubectl top pods" & "kubectl top nodes", Now I want to scrape the metrics to prometheus outside kubernetes cluster to be shown on Grafana, What I have tried are

1. Expose the metrics-server service using NodePort but not working, some https issue appear
2. Install metrics-server-exporter from https://github.com/ghouscht/metrics-server-exporter/ (this one only scrape few metrics, I cannot see it on grafana) and https://github.com/grupozap/metrics-server-exporter/ (this one is not an http application, so I cannot expose as a NodePort Service)

What should I do?

Comment: Did you apply the `With CA Cert` in Grafana during the data source setup?

Comment: I'm just using http for both prometheus and grafana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these out and let me know.

1.First you should run kube-state-metrics which collects all kubernetes metrics .

2.Using pod annotations on the kube-state-metrics , expose metrics like

```
prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
prometheus.io/port: 'port'
prometheus.io/path: '/metrics'
prometheus.io/scheme: 'http'
```

This should expose your metrics from the pod level . To check this you can exec in to the pod and do a curl request on the port followed by the path

3.Now run a prometheus agent which can scrape metrics from this port and send it to the backend db server

4.Configure prometheus ds in your grafana agent and it should be done

Comment: thanks for the info, kube-state-metrics works fine, but should I scrape all nodePort ip from prometheus? or 1 nodePort is enough? where should I put pod annotation like you said? is it on deployment spec? on my Grafana the pods list is show but no data for CPU, Memory, Bandwith usage https://prnt.sc/witosr, I'm using this template https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/12120

Comment: its working now, I don't know some metrics are different on grafana dashboard template, so I need to edit by myself ex: kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes{pod="$pod", container=~"$container"} i edited to kube_pod_container_resource_requests{pod="$pod", resource="memory", container=~"$container"}

Comment: I don't understand how this can be accepted answer, when initial question for Prometheus instance outside of Kubernetes cluster? New question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457308/add-kubernetes-scrape-target-to-prometheus-instance-that-is-not-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [helm](https://helm.sh/) to install [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#kube-prometheus-stack).

It will install [`Node Exporter`](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter), [`kube-state-metrics`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) and [`prometheus operator`](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) along with other dependencies to allow you to monitor your cluster.

You can install it by using:

```
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
helm repo update
helm install [RELEASE_NAME] prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

Once it is installed you can visit your grafana URL and configure dashboard.

You can add prometheus as data source [`Configuration` -> `Data Source`] in grafana (prometheus URL should be set by default) and import [kubernetes dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/6417) to show you summary metrics about containers running on Kubernetes nodes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but for know I'm still learning and I prefer installing manualy one by one, so I can understand what happen in my k8s cluster