# Scrapping from the default kubelet and metrics-server with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I want to scrap metrics from the default kubelet and metrics-server with Prometheus in the kube-system namespace. How can I accomplish that?

I tried to use this configuration, but it didn't work. I have: Get "https://InternalIP:443/metrics": dial tcp: lookup InternalIP on 10.96.128.2:53: no such host.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 1s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: metrics-server
        scheme: https
        static_configs:
          - targets: [metrics-server]
```

Please help, I've been trying a lot.
Thanks :)

Comment: Your question lacks clarity as to how you're deploying Prometheus and what errors you're seeing. Metrics server uses a self-signed cert and so you'll need to add `tls_config` block at the same identation level as `scheme` and `tls_config` should contain an indented value `insecure_skip_verify: true`. If you're deploying Prometheus outside of `kube-system` namespace, you should reference Metrics server as `metrics-server.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config), you should include the port number of the host on your configmap data, see below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 1s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: metrics-server
        scheme: https
        static_configs:
          - targets: [metrics-server:8080]

## check the service port number of the kube state metrics server
```

Alternatively, [this solution}([How to scrape metrics-server to prometheus outside kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621273/how-to-scrape-metrics-server-to-prometheus-outside-kubernetes-cluster)) will need you to add annotations on your kube state metrics deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-state-metrics
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.10.0
  name: kube-state-metrics
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations: 
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: 'port'
    prometheus.io/path: '/metrics'
    prometheus.io/scheme: 'http'
```

You can view yaml files of kube state metrics [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/examples/standard/deployment.yaml)